# How do I make a function that returns the equation from the argument?

Tags: r, function

For example, I have a function with the arguments "x", "d" and "equation". The "x" argument is my data frame, the "d" argument is the numeric data frame column, and in "equation" argument I wanted to insert the equation "d * 5 ^ 0.02".

As an output, I need to have a new column "V" in the data frame, with the result of the argument equation.

My idea went wrong:

```
myfunction <- function(x, d, equation, ...){

x$V <- equation

}

myfunction(x=x, d = x$d, equation = c("d"*5^0.02))
```

Comment: Add `return(x)` to your function.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```r
myfunction <- function(x, d, equation, ...) x$v <<- eval(substitute(equation))

x <- data.frame(d = 1:5)

myfunction(x=x, d = x$d, equation = d*5^0.02)

x
#>   d        v
#> 1 1 1.032712
#> 2 2 2.065425
#> 3 3 3.098137
#> 4 4 4.130850
#> 5 5 5.163562
```

---

After pondering this a bit, I wonder if you are trying to reinvent `within`?

```
within(x, v <- d*5^0.02)
#>   d        v
#> 1 1 1.032712
#> 2 2 2.065425
#> 3 3 3.098137
#> 4 4 4.130850
#> 5 5 5.163562
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think `<<-` is a really bad idea in general (I sometimes wished R made side-effect function naming conventions easy, such as `myfunction!(x, x$d, d*5^0.02)` (the extra bang)). How about `x$V <- eval(substitute(equation), envir=x); x` instead? (Adding the `envir=` as well.)

Comment: @r2evans I know, I (almost) never use `<<-` myself. I think the whole set up here is wrong. I'd probably rather just return the whole data frame, but then it would be better to just use `within`. Come to think of it, maybe that's what the OP is trying to reinvent here. I'll update.

Comment: Sorry, just posted an augmenting answer that includes `within`. :-)

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. But the second part I did according to r2evans.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want `equation` applied to `x$d`, and the result to be written to `x$V`.

Providing an "equation" like that is very unusual, and prone to error. Consider creating a function: `f <- function(x) x * 5^0.02`, and then doing the following.

```
# dummy data
x <- data.frame(d = 1:10)

# your equation
f <- function(x) x * 5^0.02

g <- function(x, d, f) {

  # call function f with column d as its argument
  x$V <- f(x[[d]]))
  return(x)
}

g(x, "d", f)

  d        V
1 1 1.032712
2 2 2.065425
3 3 3.098137
4 4 4.130850
5 5 5.163562
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers. However, functions that operate in side-effect preclude things like: assign to a new variable (one answer suggests a way to do this), or operate within a pipeline (e.g., `%>%`).

I suggest not using side-effect (`<<-` and `assign`).

```r
myfunction <- function(x, d, equation, ...) {
  x$V <- eval(substitute(equation), envir = x)
  x
}

x <- data.frame(d = 1:5)
myfunction(x, x$d, d*5^0.02)
#   d        V
# 1 1 1.032712
# 2 2 2.065425
# 3 3 3.098137
# 4 4 4.130850
# 5 5 5.163562
```

The original `x` is unchanged. One advantage to using a *functional* vice *side-effect* paradigm is that it will flow better in (say) pipes:

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  myfunction(d, d*5^0.02)
#   d        V
# 1 1 1.032712
# 2 2 2.065425
# 3 3 3.098137
# 4 4 4.130850
# 5 5 5.163562
```

whereas using side-effect might not be affecting the `x` that is intended/desired.

```r
x %>%
  filter(between(d, 2, 4)) %>%
  myfunction(d, d*5^0.02)
#   d        V
# 1 2 2.065425
# 2 3 3.098137
# 3 4 4.13085
```

(This does not work when side-effect is used.)

Alternatively, we already have a function in base R for that:

```r
within(x, { V = d*5^0.02 })
#   d        V
# 1 1 1.032712
# 2 2 2.065425
# 3 3 3.098137
# 4 4 4.130850
# 5 5 5.163562

transform(x, V = d*5^0.02 )
#   d        V
# 1 1 1.032712
# 2 2 2.065425
# 3 3 3.098137
# 4 4 4.130850
# 5 5 5.163562
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can return to the global environment direct:

```
x <- data.frame(c(1:2,5:6),c(7:10))
x
colnames(x) <- c("V1","d")
myfunction <- function(x, d, equation,named.df="NA" ,...){

  x$V <- equation
  assign(named.df,x, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

myfunction(x=x, d = x$d, equation = c(x$d*5^0.02),"function result" )
```